# How I put numbers in the contourn lines of the last graphic?

Tags: graphics

```
data = Import[
"/Users/CarmenGonzalez/Desktop/experiencia/\
excelfinalparaomathematica.xlsx"][[3]];
SetOptions[{ListContourPlot, ListPlot3D}, ImageSize -> 500];
{p2 = ListContourPlot[data, FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 13], 
ContourLines -> True, Contours -> 20, AspectRatio -> 17/25, 
ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", 
FrameLabel -> {"x (cm)", "y (cm)"}]}
data = Import[
"/Users/CarmenGonzalez/Desktop/experiencia/\
excelfinalparaomathematica.xlsx"][[3]];
yl = Length[data];
xl = Length[Transpose[data]];
lista = {};
For[j = 1, j <= yl, j++,
  For[i = 1, i <= xl, i++,
    ponto = {i, j, data[[j]][[i]]};
    lista = Append[lista, ponto];
   ];
 ];
p1 = StreamPlot[grad[x, y], {x, 1, xl}, {y, 1, yl}, 
StreamStyle -> Black, FrameLabel -> {"x (cm)", "y (cm)"}, 
PlotLabel -> 
"Linhas de campo elétrico criadas por uma carga e uma barra", 
LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, Black, 8]]
g3 = Show[{p2, p1}, FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 14], 
AspectRatio -> 17/30, ImageSize -> 1000, 
FrameLabel -> {"x (cm)", "y (cm)"}, 
PlotLabel -> 
"Representação das linhas de campo elétrico e das superfícies \
equipotenciais criados por uma carga e uma barra", 
LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, Black, 14]]
```

Comment: The file with the data is: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2i6ze1spgn0717l/excelfinalparaomathematica.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: I want to something like this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/uykgxbs8i33bx25/ajusteEquipotenciais2D.jpg?dl=0